# Using javaagent to get program arguments

Tags: java

I am trying to get the main program agrument using javaagent. Lets say I entered something like:

```
java -jar -javaagent:[path of agent file] foo.jar arg0 arg1 arg2
```

The javaagent should print:

```
arg0 arg1 arg2
```

I have tried using this code:

```
public static void premain(String ignoredArgs, Instrumentation ignoredVar){
    RuntimeMXBean runtimeMXBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
    List<String> arguments = runtimeMXBean.getInputArguments();
    System.out.println(arguments);
}
```

But it only prints the arguments before the `-javaagent` argument and itself.
Any help?

Comment: that's an interesting question, don't understand the downvote

Answer (score 1):

My approach, is using the agent itself to instrument all `public static main(String[] args)` methods to redirect the execution to a custom listener, passing the arguments of the caller.

Then, the first time the listener is executed (main method you are interested),
you get access to those arguments, and additionally you can disable
that particular instrumentation (to avoid overhead when loading future classes containing a main method), and also the listener itself (just in case multiple main methods were instrumented at that time)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("sun.java.command"));
```